qt opengl in WASM - what are the used apis end to end
I'm looking some content to better understand what is the execution path of a graphical app embedded into a WASM component run by a web browser.
The WASM embeds an executable with all the dependencies linked statically. I wonder what layers of the system run by the browser execute  the open gl calls at the end. More specifically what is the path between the WASM and the GPU?
Do you know any material to read to help understand the way it actually works. I understand that the are some limitations based on open gl ES 3.0 to port an open gl based app into a WASM.
For instance some shaders like the geometry shader are not supported.
We had to modify our code to make it work.
It is to be noted that our C++ code uses Qt open gl API not the native open gl C API.

As far as I know, WASM uses WebGL, not OpenGL-es. WebGL should be supported by all major browser, so the the execution in WASM is the same as on any "normal" WebGL page. If you are using emscripten, read OpenGL support in Emscripten. If you are using something else, then please specify what you are actually using. There's also some information here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/155391/my-experience-using-opengl-on-the-wasm-platform

@BDL I had a look to the emscripten support for open gl link before posting my question. Still I don't see what gets called at the end. Will the Qt based code run into an windows app use the same call stack compared to the one integrated into a WASM and run into a browser on the same operating system. The khronos web page on webgl spec says "WebGL™ is a cross-platform, royalty-free open web standard for a low-level 3D graphics API based on OpenGL ES". Does based on mean inspired from but implies a different instruction set ? I undesrstand this may be browser dependant.

from this https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/specs/1.0/#6 I understand there are 2 differents API. What is common underneath ?
